# Query is slow, which fields to index

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, innodb

I have this query:

```
select * from
```

When I execute it, it takes ~45sec with 35k records. Every day I add 5k+ new records to `gps_unit_location` table. So table will grow. 
My current indexes on all id's. Will adding any additional indexes would help me to improve the performance of this query?

thanks.

Comment: Please, update your question with an `EXPLAIN` at the least. And optimally a `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @njk, I added create tables

Comment: @Sebas, the query is on top

Comment: got it, I'll have a look in a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So,

1. be sure you have `NOT NULL` columns and indices on:

   ```
   INDEX ON gps_unit_location.idgps_unit_location
   INDEX ON user.iduser
   INDEX ON user_to_gps_unit.iduser
   INDEX ON user_to_gps_unit.idgps_unit
   INDEX ON gps_unit.idgps_unit
   INDEX ON gps_unit_location.idgps_unit
   ```
2. be sure you really need to select all the fields with that star `*`
3. try this query:

   ```
   SELECT 
       `gps_unit`.`idgps_unit`, 
       `gps_unit`.`name as name`, 
       `gps_unit`.`notes as notes`, 
       `gps_unit`.`serial`, 
       `gps_unit_location`.`dt` as dt, 
       `gps_unit_location`.`idgps_unit_location`,
       `gps_unit_location`.`lat`, 
       `gps_unit_location`.`long`,
       `ip`,
       `unique_id`,
       `loc_age`,
       `reason_code`,
       `speed_kmh`,
       `VehHdg`,
       `Odometer`,
       `event_time_gmt_unix`,
       `switches`,
       `engine_on_off`
   FROM user 
   INNER JOIN user_to_gps_unit  ON user.iduser = user_to_gps_unit.iduser 
   INNER JOIN gps_unit          ON user_to_gps_unit.idgps_unit = gps_unit.idgps_unit
   INNER JOIN gps_unit_location ON gps_unit.idgps_unit = gps_unit_location.idgps_unit
   INNER JOIN
           (SELECT
                `gps_unit_location`.`idgps_unit`,
                MAX(`gps_unit_location`.`dt`) dtmax
            FROM `gps_unit_location`
            GROUP BY 1
            ) r1 ON r1.idgps_unit = gps_unit_location.idgps_unit AND r1.dtmax = gps_unit_location.dt
   WHERE 
       user.iduser = 14
   ```

On a side note, I think you don't need the unique indexes on the columns that are defined as primary keys, this causes write overhead on insert/update statements.

Comment: query optimized. Please double check results.

Comment: I'm kind of looking forward to you testing it hehehe :-)

Comment: ,it works! You managed to cut execution time from 45 seconds to 29 seconds! Nevertheless, it is just 40k records! How would it asct with 1mil records? 

Do you have any idea about how to improve it even more?

Comment: When I execute this part of the query `SELECT
             gps_unit_location.idgps_unit,
             MAX(gps_unit_location.dt) dtmax
         FROM gps_unit_location
         GROUP BY 1`
it takes 18 seconds

Comment: yes, that's the consumming part. Use the EXPLAIN option on this query only and check whether the index is used

Comment: id='1', select type='SIMPLE', table='gps_unit_location', type='index', possible keys=NULL, key='fk_gps2', key len='5', ref=NULL, rows='368668', extra=''

Comment: well then, your database is just slow. You should consider auditing this query and see how your hardware/softwares could be modified to improve it. What's the CPU?

Answer (score 1):

The generic answer is to index those columns that are used to join and constrain (ON and WHERE clauses).  Use composite indexes (joins first, then constraints next with the lowest cardinality constraints first).

Oh, and make all your IDs 'unsigned'.